# Как записать cookies в БД, чтобы потом их можно было использовать?

Tags: python, база-данных, json, django

Мое приложение на джанге при запуске логинится в сервисе, но мне бы хотелось логинится намного реже. В ответе при логине я могу получить некие settings вместе с куками и выполнять запросы уже без повторного логина.
Проблема в следующем, этот самый settings не получается записать в БД так, чтобы потом его можно было использовать. Пробовал json, pickle, ast - ничего не помогает. Уверен есть простое решение, но найти не могу.

Получаю вот такой ответ при логине (тот самый settings):

```
{'uuid': '684e482c-71d0-11eb-444-8c85909e71ef', 'device_id': 'android-684444c71d011eb', 'ad_id': 'edcc444-046b-5d45-3dcb-381fc284e0af', 'session_id': '684e444-71d0-444-b6c3-8c85909e71ef', 'cookie': b'\x80\x04\x95\xdf\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94\x8c\x0e.instagram.com\x94}\x94\x8c\x01/\x94}\x94(\x8c\tcsrftoken\8c\x06Cookie\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94}\x94(\x8c\x07version\x94K\x00\x8c\x04name\x94\x8c\tcsrftoken\x94\x8c\x05value\x94\x8c\x10domain_specified\x94\x88\x8c\x12domain_initial_dot\x94\x88\x8c\x04path\x94h\x03\x8c\x0epath_specified\x94\x88\x8c\x06secure\x94\x88\x8c\x07expires\x94JE\x1d\x0eb\x8c\x07discard\x94\x89\x8c\x07comment\x94N\x8c\x0bcomment_url\x94N\x8c\x07rfc2109\x94\x89\x8c\x05_rest\x94}\x94ub\x8c\x03mid\x94h\x08)\x81\x94}\x94(h\x0bK\x00h\x0ch h\x0e\x8c\x1cYC47NAABAAEFnbHpiMh\x10Nh\x11\x89h\x12\x8c\x0e.instagram.com\x94h\x14\x88h\x15\x88h\x16h\x03h\x17\x88h\x18\x88h\x19J4\xa2\xf0ch\x1a\x89h\x1bNh\x1cNh\x1d\x89h\x1e}\x94ubuss.', 'created_ts': 1613642759}
```

Comment: request.Session() если коротко, он нормально пишеться в pickle

Comment: @Jack_oS мне нужно именно эти данные использовать, а не сессию

Comment: Через модуль json сделайте из них строку и сохраните ее в поле таблицы базы

Comment: @gil9red Это не json, а все попытки превратить его в json не увенчались успехом

Comment: @EduardKumskyi, `{'uuid': '684e482c-71d0-11eb-b6c3-8c85909e71ef', 'device_id': 'android-684e5ccc71d011eb', 'ad_id': 'edcc85b0-046b-5d45-3dcb-381fc284e0af', 'session_id': '684e5eca-71d0-11eb-b6c3-8c85909e71ef', 'cookie': b'...', 'created_ts': 1613642759}` выглядит именно как JSON. Возможно, нужно значение в cookie из байтового массива (там был префикс `b`: `b'...'`) закодировать в base64

Comment: @gil9red
я пытался отдельно работать с ключом cookie, но после того, как он превращается в строку, он обратно не дампится
алгоритм такой:
достал ключ cookie
потом pickle.dumps
потом это в базу, после чего значение становится строкой
теперь pickle.loads
и на выходе получаю то же что и было, только немного байтов в начале строки, все не превращается в байты почему то

Comment: `pickle.dumps` массив байт возвращает, как вы его в базу записываете? В BLOB? Или вы его кодируете в `base64`/`hex` и сохраняете как строку?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119910/discussion-between-eduard-kumskyi-and-gil9red).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.

Оказалось есть специальный тип в поля в Django ORM, для байтов (models.BinaryField). Разбил эти данные на 2 части, 1 - куки, в том виде, в котором они предоставляются (BinaryField), 2 - все данные, где ключ 'cookie' заменил на обычный текст.

```
    # wrie settings TO DB
    settings = get_settings()
    cookie = settings['cookie']
    settings['cookie'] = 'empty'
    body = settings
    Settings.objects.update_or_create(id=1, defaults={'body': body, 'cookie': cookie})
    # get settings FROM DB
    import ast
    settings = Settings.objects.get(id=1).body
    settings = ast.literal_eval(settings)
    settings['cookie'] = bytes(Settings.objects.get(id=1).cookie)
```